# Passagem de parâmetro entre páginas

Tags: c#, query, windows-phone, parâmetros, windows-phone-8-1

**Como fazer a passagem de parâmetro entre páginas no Windows Phone 8 .1?**

Na versão anterior era feito assim:

Pag 1:

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
   string uri = string.Format("/Pagina2.xaml?nomeParametro={0}", txtValor.Text);

   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, uriKind.Relative));  
  }
```

Pag 2 :

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
   if (NavigationContext.QueryString["nomeParametro"] != null)
  txtParametro.Text = NavigationContext.QueryString["nomeParametro"];

 base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Porém na versão atual não é mais possível utilizar o `NavigationContext`.

Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na versão 8.1 você passa a usar a navegação a partir do *Frame* da página, e recebe o parâmetro a partir do objeto passado ao método OnNavigatedTo:

pag 1:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string parametro = txtValor.Text;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Pagina2), parametro);
}
```

pag 2:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    txtParametro.Text = (string)e.Parameter;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para navegar entre as páginas, devemos usar o método Navigate(Type pageType). E para incluir parâmetros, usamos o método Navigate(Type pageType, object param).

Por exemplo, considere uma página chamada BasicPage1. Desejamos a partir dela navegar para outra página passando um parâmetro. Para tanto:

Na classe BasicPage1:

```
    private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage2), tb1.Text);
    }
```

Na classe BasicPage2:

```
    private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e) {
        string message = e.NavigationParameter as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) {
            tb1.Text = "Hello, " + name;
        }
    }
```

Para um exemplo mais detalhado, por favor acesse o [link](http://talkitbr.com/2015/06/16/problemas-navegacao-entre-paginas-no-windows-phone/)